# Simple but fast binary file de/encryption using PHP

Tags: php, encryption

I need to implement a simple (not ultra-secure) but fast file en/decryption using PHP, so files are encrypted on upload and decrypted on download. Files are mainly images (jpg) and videos (mp4), and some videos are up to 30 MB, so my idea is to encrypt only the first X bytes of each file, just to avoid anyone that could have access to the server (ie. support people) to open the files from users.

I am new to this subject and after almost 6 hours researching found only old examples, using deprecated Mcrypt.

Please, can anyone give me tips to start? Is there any native method from PHP that I can use, or maybe an open-source library? Does Mcrypt would be an option, even if deprecated (I am using PHP 5.6). Do you think encrypting only the first X bytes of the file is a good approach in my case?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to set up a permission system instead of tampering files?

Comment: "Do you think encrypting only the first X bytes of the file" Of course not. You are making a huge assumption that files are useless when the first bytes are not readable. Why would you encrypt only the first x bytes?

Comment: @Eric, users could give FTP access to support people, in order to solve problems.

Comment: @PeeHaa, as I said in the question I am new to this subject. I read this approach somewhere long time ago. I think encrypting only the first X bytes would make things fast...

Comment: That doesn't explain why you don't want to encrypt the entire files.

Comment: @PeeHaa, I think encrypting only the first X bytes of the file would make things faster and use less resources from the server, don't?

Comment: You assume and think a lot of things. It hardly makes sense to make decisions on hunches and wild guesses.

Comment: What about encrypt the whole file, do you know a PHP method or library that can I use?

Comment: Unfortunatelly some people here in SOF add comments only for criticize... If you do not know or want to help, please just ignore.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a PHP encryption library: https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption

I found this just by googling, I can't vouch for it's reliability or security. There are documentation and examples on that page.

However I really would ask you to take a step back and consider what the purpose of this is and what the wider security considerations are. In order to do this successfully then there will need to be some security secret, either a key or a password, that will need to be kept hidden from the people that you don't want to be able to decipher the data. I can imagine that would be difficult if those people are the support staff. If you made the password the users login password you are setting yourself up for widespread data loss when a user forgets their password. Also at some point it will need to be unencrypted and you will need to think about making sure that is not  leaked at this point. And then you need to think about who has access to the source code that handles the file access, and the key/password code. What about server logs and caches? Etc etc

Furthermore if you are only encrypting the first X number of bytes and don't need to make it 'ultra-secure' then I wonder why you are attempting to do it this way at all? I'm not sure what problem it is you are trying to solve.

Given that doing encryption properly is not simple (not to mention costly in terms of computing resources), but if you don't do it properly it isn't much good then I can't help suspect you will probably be much better off spending the effort making sure that untrusted persons only access information on a need-to-know basis and all access is logged in order to keep people honest.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me! You are completely right in your comments. I will check the library you suggested but also I will think what else can be done to avoid the needed of file encryption.

Comment: This is actually a good library to recommend. It gives authenticated encryption.